# Adding Multiple Records to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-records

I have a customer database I would like to add a set of Card numbers to.  In the table there are multiple columns that will be the same, however the Card number will increase by 1 until finished.  So for example... I want to add Gift cards 1 - 250 with the other columns the same... so it would like something like this:

```
Cardnum      price    booktype   service 
1             9.99       1         12 
2             9.99       1         12
3             9.99       1         12
```

etc etc... This would repeat until cardnum was '250' Is it possible to do this with an SQL Query?

Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS? A simple auto-increment on Cardnum will take care of this, with 250 identical inserts.

Comment: SQL Server. Does it need to be a stored function?  WOuld it be something like select startnum, endnum from cardtable while startnum > endnum?  I'm unsure how to insert the multiple values..and what to "select" in the update obviously @ infront of the startnum and endnum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jimdrang already provided the answer, but since I was just finishing a full example with the CREATE TABLE and a stored procedure to do the job, I guess I might as well post it for the benefit of anyone looking for this down the road.

```
CREATE TABLE Cards
(
  Cardnum int not null primary key,
  price money not null,
  booktype int not null,
  service int not null
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AddCards] (
  @Price money,
  @BookType int,
  @Service int,
  @NumCards int,
  @StartNum int
)
  AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @CurCard int
  SELECT @CurCard = @StartNum

  WHILE @CurCard < @StartNum + @NumCards
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Cards (Cardnum, price, booktype, service)
    VALUES (@CurCard, @Price, @BookType, @Service)

    SELECT @CurCard = @CurCard + 1
  END
END

GO

EXEC sp_AddCards @Price=9.99, @BookType=1, @Service=12, @NumCards=250, @Startnum=810041;

SELECT * FROM Cards;

DROP TABLE Cards;
DROP PROCEDURE sp_AddCards;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all make the cardnum as 'identity'(seed value will be 1). Then in a while loop from 1 to 250 just write an insert statement for the rest three colums. I hope you can write the code yourself.

Comment: I was initially thinking: 

SELECT start, end 
WHILE start <= end
begin
INSERT INTO cardtable(cardnum = start, price = '9.99', booktype = '1', service = '12')
VALUES(start)
SET start = start + 1
END

Comment: Which isns't quite it... I am confused about the multiple inserts into the table durring the "while"

Answer (score 1):

Since the table already exists, try this:

```
DECLARE @book INT
SET @book = 810041
WHILE (@book) < 810291
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableName
    VALUES(@book,9.99,1,12)
    SET @book = @book +1
END
```

Assuming you are using SQL-Server 2005 or later and want to create this table from scratch:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#books](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [price] decimal(6,2) NULL,
        [bookType] [int] NULL,
        [service] [int] NULL)

    INSERT INTO #books
    VALUES(9.99,1,12)
    GO 250
```

Comment: The table already exists. I'm "updating" the table to include 250 identical cards (just different numbers).  It's also not going 1 - 250 it's actually like 810041 - 8100291 so they will need to be variables.

Comment: Check my previous comment, it will need to be a variable.

Comment: Do I need to define the Columns? or does it just insert in order?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` DDL still isn't correct. The question calls for a user-generated key, which an IDENTITY column simply won't do for you (barring `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, which in this case just lets you get around the fact that the schema doesn't match the requirements). Admittedly, I would let the dbms handle key generation itself, personally, unless I had a compelling reason to do otherwise, but that wasn't the desired behavior here.

Comment: The question didn't specify this. I edited my answer when I had this information, but left the original answer intact since it was similar and may prove useful to those looking for an option without a user-generated key

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a stored procedure to achieve this and the code goes thus

```
declare @cnt int

set @cnt = 0
while(@cnt < 250)
begin
insert into dbo.xxx(price, booktype, servic) 
values(9, 1, 12)

set @cnt = @cnt + 1
end
```

Comment: You can set `@cnt` to any value, declare a variable `@end` to replace 250